# Get Number of PDF Pages in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, pdf

How can I output the number of pages in a PDF in the Terminal? I looked into the `lp` family of commands, with no luck however.

Comment: What are you really looking for?  In other words, are you just looking for a numeric value as the only output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Apple's `mdls`:

```
 mdls -name kMDItemNumberOfPages file.pdf
```

to get just the number of pages:

```
 mdls -name kMDItemNumberOfPages -raw file.pdf
```

Comment: Built-in and does exactly what I need. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pdf command line tools (xpdf) from [foolabs.com](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html)

There's `pdfinfo` which outputs something like this:

```
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          4
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter) (rotated 0 degrees)
File size:      134885 bytes
Optimized:      yes
PDF version:    1.4
```

So You can get number of pages with:

```
pdfinfo /path/to/file.pdf | grep Pages
```